# Android app development error: unable to run on android app version error

Tags: android

I am running my app on my htc desire. The app runs fine on phone sometimes then it starts giving me error of 
[2014-08-29 10:29:24 - testa] ERROR: Application requires API version 20. Device API version is 15 (Android 4.0.3).
[2014-08-29 10:29:24 - testa] Launch canceled!

Even though a while i ran the same app on the same phone. The error goes away sometimes then come back.
I also changed the phone to other android phone and same thing happens.

Comment: You have to set your target version to 20

Comment: please post your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have define min sdk version as 20 in your config.xml, please replace/add the below line in your config.xml file

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That is my androidManifest.xml file.I think the version is 20.I am sure i chose the right version. It works then it stops working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="21" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="20"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The problem is with your android.minsdkversion, you have assigned higher version, make it 7. for ref visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

Answer (score 0):

It worked.I changed the version from 1 to 7. Thank you everyone for your quick help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="21" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```